# How do you create a database from a backup with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, database-restore, pgadmin-4, postgres-10

In SQL Server, I can create a new database on the server from a backup from another box. I can't seem to find that functionality in pgAdmin4 with PostgreSQL10. It seems like all I can do is restore an existing database. Do I need to just create a blank database first?

Comment: There is always a `pg_dumpall` command https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-ALL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `--create` or `-C` in `pg_dump` function to make database. From [*Documentation*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) :

> Begin the output with a command to create the database itself and
>   reconnect to the created database. (With a script of this form, it
>   doesn't matter which database in the destination installation you
>   connect to before running the script.)

For syntax :

```
pg_dump -C -U your_user -d your_db > filename.sql
```

or

```
pg_dump --create -U your_user -d your_db > filename.sql
```